# Trying to pass the following client

Tags: rust

This is the original code I have in Rust that currently works:

```
let rt = runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap(); 
rt.block_on(async {
    let tcp = TcpStream::connect(config.get_addr()).await?;
    tcp.set_nodelay(true)?;
   
    let mut client = Client::connect(config, TokioAsyncWriteCompatExt::compat_write(tcp)).await?;

    let table_name = format!("Authorities{}", self.year);
    let schema_table_name = format!("TaxStatements.{}", table_name);
    log::info!("table_name {:?}", table_name);
    log::info!("schema_table_name {:?}", schema_table_name);
    let query = format!(r#"
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TaxStatements' AND  TABLE_NAME = '{table_name}'))
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE {schema_table_name}
    END"#, table_name = table_name, schema_table_name = schema_table_name);
    
    log::info!("query {:?}", query);
    client.execute(query, &[&schema_table_name]).await?;

    client.close().await?;

    Ok(true)
})
```

But when I try to move the drop query to another function, I keep getting errors when passing the client to the function:

```
let rt = runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap(); 
rt.block_on(async {
    let tcp = TcpStream::connect(config.get_addr()).await?;
    tcp.set_nodelay(true)?;
   
    let mut client = Client::connect(config, TokioAsyncWriteCompatExt::compat_write(tcp)).await?;

    self.drop_table(&mut client).await?;

    Ok(true)
})


async fn drop_table(&self, client: &mut Client<dyn TokioAsyncWriteCompatExt<TcpStream>>) -> Result<(), AuthoritiesError> {

    let table_name = format!("Authorities{}", self.year);
    let schema_table_name = format!("TaxStatements.{}", table_name);
    log::info!("table_name {:?}", table_name);
    log::info!("schema_table_name {:?}", schema_table_name);
    let query = format!(r#"
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TaxStatements' AND  TABLE_NAME = '{table_name}'))
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE {schema_table_name}
    END"#, table_name = table_name, schema_table_name = schema_table_name);
    
    log::info!("query {:?}", query);
    client.execute(query, &[&schema_table_name]).await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Here is the following error indicated on the function

```
client: &mut Client<dyn TokioAsyncWriteCompatExt<TcpStream>>:
trait takes 0 generic arguments, but one generic argument was supplied
```

But if I look at the Client docs, it says:

```rust
tiberius::client
pub struct Client<S>
where
    S: AsyncRead + AsyncWrite + Unpin + Send, {
    pub(crate) connection: Connection<S>,
}
```

and connect returns: `crate::Result<Client<S>>`

I've tried different function declarations like

```
async fn drop_tablea(&self, client: &mut Client) -> Result<(), AuthoritiesError>
```

But I just get the error missing generics for struct `tiberius::Client`

I've tried other options but there doesn't seem to be one that works for me.

Answer (score 2):

`Client` is a struct! That means the error is talking about something different in that line, namely the `TokioAsyncWriteCompatExt` **trait**, which does not take a type parameter, so change this `dyn TokioAsyncWriteCompatExt<TcpStream>` to this `dyn TokioAsyncWriteCompatExt`